# Updating PK values mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a 2 tables that I wish to update `articles` and `articles_entities` articles has a PK of `id` and articles_entities has the FK `article_id` both these fields are char(36) currently a UUID. I am looking to convert these fields to int(10).

Is there a way I can update the 2 tables with 1 query and key the keys matching? or do I have to write a script to look through each articles and update all references?

I am using InnoDb if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two steps:

1. Ensure your foreign key is set to "ON UPDATE CASCADE", then update the mother table's ID field so it contains numbers. The ON UPDATE CASCADE constraint will have InnoDB update the child table as it updates the mother... If you have a lot of rows, be prepared that this will be extremely slow.
2. Change the type of both columns to INT. You may need to drop the foreign key before you do so and re-create it afterwards.